# How to select text in a tag with xpath scrapy?

Tags: python, facebook, xpath, scrapy

I want to select the text inside these tags, how can I select them ( i want to select the name and comment in a post on the Facebook fan page)?

- I have 2 div tags like this

```
<div class="_2b05">
    <a href="/profile.php?id=100003980635623&amp;fref=nf&amp;rc=p&amp;__tn__=R">
        <div class="_7_cb _3-8m">
        <i class="_3-8_ img sp_VfPHLawdqPX sx_0636a9"></i>
        Fan cứng
        </div>
        Hải Ka
        </a>
    </div><div data-commentid="511961943618859" data-sigil="comment-body">
    Ráng lướt rồi cũng sẽ qua<span class="_5mfr"><span class="_6qdm" style="height: 16px; width: 16px; font-size: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/t81/1/16/1f60c.png&quot;)"></span></span></div>



<div class="_2b05">
    <a href="/leminhnhut2110?fref=nf&amp;rc=p&amp;__tn__=R">
    Lê Minh Nhựt</a>
    </div>
    <div data-commentid="511968943618159" data-sigil="comment-body">Làm ngụm Oolong cho phẻ m.n êijii</div>
```

i succeced to select comments by use xpath like this

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@data-sigil,"comment-body")]/text()')
```

but with the name there are some problem with Fan tag. i used this xpath:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@data-sigil,"comment-body")]//preceding-sibling::div/a/text()')
```

it only show the comment's user name if not have Fan text. How can i skip Fan text and only choose text contain the name of user? Thanks

Some pic about it:
[image]
with Fan text:
[image]
without Fan text:
[image]

update: sorry, my problem is not fan text. You can read my conversation between me and sir F.Hoque to know more. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@data-sigil,"comment-body")]/text()')
```

**Output:**

(The above xpath selection  will return the following output)

```
Ráng lướt rồi cũng sẽ qua
Làm ngụm Oolong cho phẻ m.n êijii
```

Select user name:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="_2b05"]/a/text()')
```

Output:

```
 Hải Ka
Lê Minh Nhựt
```

Comment: yes, it will return list of comment. Now what i need to do just select list of username

Comment: facebook is generate class random in timeline, i can't use class to select :((

Comment: Your user name selection  xpath also  produces  the same output

Comment: Hmmm, i see it. Sr sir. Now i'm going to find why number of comment and username is not equal :(( i thought that because fan text, in this post, have 30 comment and 30 username, have 2 fan text show the resultshow is 30 comment and 28 username, i thought it was because fan text :((, here is the link [link](https://touch.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=511921346956252&id=100044151743994)

Comment: Some users didn't comment just use emoji but  in scrapy output   that will be showed as None

Comment: yes sir :((. and if they use icon middle comment, it will will split that comment into 2 or more comments. How can i stop that split process? or what is the best way to select user name and comment correctly

Comment: use //text() then getall() and after all use "".join()

Comment: As I can't test your code so I can't  say  a bit more

Comment: Hmmm, it seem hard to use getall sir, cause `response.xpath('//div[contains(@data-sigil,"comment-body")]/text()')` will return a list all what could get in the page, so when use getall() i dont know what comments is connect each other :((

Comment: [link code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19kN7hlLrb5B1K5b-OJhBvWg2uAgl9XOG?usp=sharing) sir, here is the code scrapy. you need to enter your email and pass of facebook in fbscraping.py file. Thanks

Comment: Actually, You have to select each items/listing then iterate and if you use relative xpath only then it's possible and  it's the rule

Comment: Ok  it's very possible to give you the solution but you have to wait

Comment: ok sir, yeah, with other pages i can easy to select each item with css select, but facebook is different. it's class and struct seem random and i can't locate the tag easily. using xpath is the best solution i have finding for 2 days :((

Comment: The last question sir. the code i'm using is only find username from div before div tag of comment. Know i find some username is in tag a child of the div cmt i find, can i get both tag a child and tag div/a before at the same time?